# If I press a currency in the actionsheet, the actionsheet appears again

Tags: ios, swift

When you press a button with a picture of your phone, I want the phone to go immediately.

However, the actionsheet corresponding to the photo is uploaded once again, and when you try to make a call by pressing the button again for the second time, it goes to the call connection screen. In code, it's obviously only being called once. Why?

```
private func settingActionSheet(phoneNumber: String) {
        let image = UIImage(named: "tellephone9")
        let menu1 = UIAlertAction(title: "\(phoneNumber)", style: .default) { action in
            // 전화 걸기
            guard let phoneNumberURL = self.phoneNumberURL else {
                return
            }

            if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(phoneNumberURL) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(phoneNumberURL)
            } else {
            }
            
        }
        menu1.setValue(image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), forKey: "image")

        let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "취소", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        actionSheet.addAction(menu1)
        actionSheet.addAction(cancel)
    }

  @IBAction func searchPassword(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(#function)
        present(actionSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zEwE.png)

Comment: Do I undertand it right that when user preses button you want to present an Alert with 2 actions?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak No.. I want to just one action.. But It doesn't lead to a direct call connection and the actionSheet pops up again. However, after that, if you press the actionSheet button, the call is connected.

Comment: `UIAlertAction` is not meant for this use , but rather to present allert with the alert action. Use `UIButton` instead